# Autoclick security for a like button

Tags: security

Hi everyone
I want to develop a button like 'facebook like button'.
I am going to use it on my website and thinking it to share as iframe like facebook but I cannot think its securty because someone can develop a script that can click on it automatically.

I thought a solution using sessions but I couldn't make an algorithm completely.

How can I disallow autoclicks and which solution is the best? It can be any language I just want algorithm.

Thanks, have a nice day.

Edited :
Think a website like facebook. I login facebook and I can click on like button on any website.

Comment: Facebook requires a login and confirmation of the like. Do you have a login, or is it open to anyone?

Comment: Will the people you expect to click on the like button have accounts on your website?

Comment: Yes I have a login but when I login I have login sessions. When I enter another website that includes a iframe from my website, my website can use my sessions and another script can click on iframe.

Comment: Which is why you should move on click to a new page where the user confirms their like.

Answer (score 0):

Move to a new page and allow the logged in user to confirm that they were the ones who clicked the like
 button.

Comment: Maybe a javascript clicks on it too. For example there is a link in iframe http://example.com/like.php?id=54545 the user goes to a new page and click on confirm, ok. Two, a javascript goes to http://example.com/like.php?id=54545, the user get new sessions but he doesn't know and javascript click on confirm. How can I make a system that can split request as user or javascipt

Comment: If you go to the new page, not load it in the iFrame, the JS cannot follow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there's a surefire way to prevent clickjacking or the type of fraud you're referring to, given that you want to place your button in an iframe.

See http://ha.ckers.org/blog/20081007/clickjacking-details/ for more info.

Comment: Yes I said this problem, now I can research about this subject. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent this, once you have generated the [like button](http://facebook.com/youlikebutton.php), the button can be access directly.
You just can protect yourself using client side defence technologies like [Comitari](http://www.comitari.com/) supplies.

They have a free product that protects you against ClickJacking and LikeJacking attacks.